# Using Regular Expression

Tags: regular-expressions

```
sample2 = "this is a test to find whether pi works for other words or not as well pi pi pi potatpi pineapple pi-neapple";
```

so `sample2` is a string, and I want to search the word/substring `"pi"` only, not in `"pi-neapple"` or `"potatpi"`

The code I tried:

```
StringCases[sample2, RegularExpression["\\b(pi)\\b"]]
```

output :

```
{"pi", "pi", "pi", "pi", "pi"}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: It's also possible to get them without the regex, `Cases[StringSplit[sample2], "pi"]`and `Cases[TextWords[sample2], "pi"]`

Comment: Another approach, which like the [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225927/106) posted by Anton.Sakovich, works if 'pi' occurs at the beginning (no space before) or end (no space after) of the string, is to use 'double-negative' delimiters with negative-lookarounds (see [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#double-negative-delimiter), the link referenced by Anton): `StringCases[sample2, RegularExpression["(?<!\\S)pi(?!\\S)"]]`.  (The regex asserts that _if_ a character occurs before or after 'pi' it must be a space. [or ... it must _not_ be not a  space])

Comment: There is a potential  "gotcha" here that I think is worth drawing attention to (I found it the hard way). `StringCases["a    pi    z", RegularExpression["\\s+(pi)\\s+"] -> "$1",Overlaps -> True]` outputs "{pi, pi, pi, pi}". (The problem, of course, is the extra spaces with the `+` quantifier). Substituting the regex `"\\s(pi)\\s"` solves the problem but both regexes (regexen?) fail with the string `"pi    pi    pi"` ('pi' at the beginning/end  is not matched). See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225911/106) for a more detailed analysis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a start, try using `\s`, which stands for any white space character.

```
StringCases[
 sample2,
 RegularExpression["\\s+(pi)\\s+"] -> "$1",
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

> {"pi", "pi", "pi", "pi"}

Read towards the end of this answer for more information on how to make this more robust.

The corresponding Wolfram Language string pattern is this:

```
StringCases[
 sample2,
 Whitespace ~~ s:"pi" ~~ Whitespace -> s,
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

> {"pi", "pi", "pi", "pi"}

It is at least functionally equivalent in this case, but it does not use the exact same regular expression. We can see what regular expression it translates the string pattern into like this:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert["[\\s\\n]+(pi)[\\s\\n]+"] // First
```

> `"(?ms)\\[\\\\s\\\\n\\]\\+\\(pi\\)\\[\\\\s\\\\n\\]\\+"`

(Mathematica threw in a couple of extra backslashes for good measure upon copying the pattern.)

## Robustification

user1066 has identified issues with the regex solution. First, it doesn't work if the string starts or ends with a `pi`. Second, it doesn't work if there are more than two spaces.

One possible way to patch the solution to work for these cases is:

```
StringCases[
 StringReplace[s, " " .. -> " "], {
  RegularExpression["\\s+(pi)\\s+"] -> "$1",
  RegularExpression["^(pi)\\s+"] -> "$1",
  RegularExpression["\\s+(pi)$"] -> "$1"
  },
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

user1066 found the following solution which neatly packs these patterns into one regex:

```
StringCases[
 s,
 RegularExpression["(?i)(^|\\s)(pi)($|\\s)"] -> "$2",
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

The extra `"pi"` in the output is simply because `-` is not a word character, and therefore `pi` in `pi-neaple` matches `\b(pi)\b`.

```
StringMatchQ["-", RegularExpression["\\w"]]
(*False*)
```

You can use the following pattern to add `-` to word characters:

```
(?<![\w\-])(pi)(?![\w\-])
```

which leads to one less `pi` in the result:

```
StringCases[
  sample2,
  RegularExpression["(?<![\\w\\-])(pi)(?![\\w\\-])"]
]
(*{"pi", "pi", "pi", "pi"}*)
```

To ensure that these are the right `pi`s, we can use the following test case:

```
StringCases[
  "pi1 foo-pi2 pi3-foo foo-pi4-bar api5 pi6peline pi7 pi8", 
   RegularExpression["(?<![\\w\\-])(pi\\d)(?![\\w\\-])"]
]
(*{"pi1", "pi7", "pi8"}*)
```

## About the pattern

The pattern `\b(pi)\b` means

> `pi` which is not preceded by a word character (`\w`) and is not followed by a word character.

All we need to do here is to replace *by a word character* with *by a word character or a dash*.

For this we can use *lookarounds*, which are explained, e.g., [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). In a nutshell, `(?<!foo)bar` means `bar` not preceded by something matching `foo`, and `foo(?!bar)` means `foo` not followed by something matching `bar`.